# Issue installing wordpress : Parse error

Tags: wordpress, installation

So I am used to install wordpress websites, but here I have no idea what went wrong or how I can solve it ? 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/XXX/XXX-kei/wp-includes/load.php on line 1073

that's the only message that I get after moving the wordpress file to my server. I don't even get to the set-up screen. 
thanks a lot for your help 
best regards
adrien

Comment: Are you installing direct from the latest release?

Comment: yes from wordpress french version but it should be the last :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same probleme and I update the php version to the 5.6 and is working now.